# Finding a Galois group using a cubic resolvent

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I've heard there's a fast way to find the Galois group of a quartic polynomial using its resolvent.  Can anyone explain how it's done or give a reference?  Is this method the same as the general resolvent method or is there something different going on here?

Comment: I can't answer your second question.  But for the first, consult section 14.6 in Dummit and Foote's third edition.

Comment: Keith Conrad wrote up a nice & thorugh discussion of the Galois groups of (cubics and) quartics, http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf